# How to manipulate a process to use X amount of mem or cpu

Tags: linux

How can I make a process that says it’s using X amount of mem or cpu in `top` or `ps`. I want to be able to trigger another script rather than wait for a users job to trigger it.

Is there any way I can change the amount in `top` or `ps` even though it’s not really doing that much?

Comment: Why do want to do that? The statistics reported by `top` or `ps` are *Measurements*!

Comment: If you want to limit cpu or mem usage of a proces, you should look after cgroups.